# CPLEX ILOG - 3 Crops across 3 Farms

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ilog

I am trying to solve 9 planting decisions for 3 crops on each of 3 farms.

I am given data for Available land on each farm, Available water on each farm, Maximum Quota for each crop, Water Consumption for each crop, and Profit for each crop.  I am not allowed to list all of the coefficients in the .dat file.

Below is what I have entered in the .dat file:

```
Farms = {Rice,Barns,Snyder};
Crops = {Corn,Wheat,SoyBeans}; 
UsableLand = [400,600,300];
Water = [600,800,375];
MaximumQuota = [600,500,325];
WaterConsumption = [3,2,1];
Profit = [1000,750,250];
```

There are 3 constraints: Usable Land, Available water, and Maximum Quota.
The Objective is to maximize profit.

Below is what I have in the .mod file which is (finally) solving with no errors but not giving me the correct answer that Excel's solver runs.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
{string} Farms = ...;
{string} Crops = ...;

int UsableLand[Farms]=...;
int Water[Farms]=...;
int MaximumQuota[Crops]=...;
int WaterConsumption[Crops]=...;
int Profit[Crops]=...;

constraint LandAcre[Farms];
constraint WaterAcre[Farms];
constraint CropLimit[Crops];

dvar float+ ProductionAmount[Crops][Farms];

maximize
  sum(i in Crops, p in Farms)
    Profit[i]*ProductionAmount[i][p];
        
subject to {
  forall(i in Farms)
    LandAcre[i]:
        sum(j in Crops, p in Farms)   ProductionAmount[j][p] <= UsableLand[i];   
  forall(i in Farms)
    WaterAcre[i]:
        sum(j in Crops, p in Farms)   WaterConsumption[j] <= Water[i]; 
  forall(i in Crops)
    CropLimit[i]:
        sum(j in Crops, p in Farms)   ProductionAmount[j][p] <= MaximumQuota[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious:

```
  forall(i in Farms)
    LandAcre[i]:
        sum(j in Crops, p in Farms)   ProductionAmount[j][p] <= UsableLand[i];
```

It probably should read:

```
  forall(i in Farms)
    LandAcre[i]:
        sum(j in Crops)   ProductionAmount[j][i] <= UsableLand[i];
```

Same for the other constraints.

A useful debugging tool is to write out the LP file and inspect that for unexpected things.

Comment: I changed to `dvar float+ ProductionAmount[Crops][Farms];

maximize
  sum(i in Crops)
    Profit[i]*ProductionAmount[i][i];
        
subject to {
  forall(i in Farms)
    LandAcre[i]:
     sum(j in Crops)   ProductionAmount[j][i] <= UsableLand[i];   
  forall(i in Farms)
    WaterAcre[i]:
     sum(j in Crops)   WaterConsumption[j] <= Water[i]; 
  forall(i in Crops)
    CropLimit[i]:
     sum(j in Crops)   ProductionAmount[j][i] <= MaximumQuota[i];
}` and am getting the error Operator not available for int * dvar float+ [ ][Farms]